# 'function' object has no attribute 'event' Eror discord bot python

Tags: python, discord.py

i have a error on line 8 'function' object has no attribute 'event' i cant fix it

```
from http import client
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
import discord  
import random

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
@Client.event
async def FunctionName():
  print('vezi ca sunt on{0.user}'.format(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Discord client variable is named `client` with a small `c`, but your decorator uses `Client` with a big C. The decorator should be registered to your Discord client instance.

`Client` (big C) refers to your import (`from multiprocessing.connection import Client`) instead of your Discord client.

```py
@client.event  # Your discord.Client instance
@Client.event  # multiprocessing.connection.Client()
```

Also a note: the `client` variable is shadowing your `http` import (`from http import client`). You should give it another name.